# RTEMS: how to compile and execute programs?

Tags: linux, compilation, real-time, rtems

I've just started my academic project: Nano Sattelites Software Infrastructure.
I installed RTEMS on CentOS and i can compile and execute sample programs, like hello or ticker.
When i'm doing any changes to existing files(init.c for example) adding new files,tasks or functions, the compilation fails. I didn't find any tutorial like step-by-step explanation how create a new program from scratch and compile it, there are only examples on how to compile existing sample files and run them...
Is anybody can help on this point?

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the [examples-v2.git](http://git.rtems.org/examples-v2/) repository for a Makefile-based approach and [Waf](https://code.google.com/p/waf/)-based approach to compile applications from outside of the RTEMS directory.

Comment: The best way is read the rtems manual. Just read it all,like a favorite book))now this is much more clear how to deal with it...

Comment: Both links are dead now. Are there working replacements?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and gedare's answer did work for me. I am sharing the updated URLs for his answer:

```
https://github.com/RTEMS/rtems-examples
```

Remeber to set the **RTEMS_MAKEFILE_PATH** variable. For me, it had to be:

```
RTEMS_MAKEFILE_PATH = /opt/rtems/4.10/sparc-rtems4.10/leon3
```

You may create an environment variable for it, or you can add this line to the top of your Makefile.

Also remember to add the toolchain bin dir to your **PATH** environment variable and use the correct version of the examples (git checkout to the correct branch after you clone the repository above.)

I hope this helps anyone out there with the same issue :)